# Logstash not producing output

Tags: linux, stdout, logstash

I have just installed logstash 1.5.3 on a Linux machine. Details:

```
$ uname -a
Linux hlt-dev 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 01:55:02 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I try to run the basic "hello world" setup

```
$ bin/logstash -e 'input {stdin { } } output { stdout { } }'
hello world
testing
```

I get nothing on stdout.  Any ideas why?  I installed this on my Windows machine and am able to run it there.

Output to file is also not working:

```
$ bin/logstash -e 'input {stdin { } } output {file {path => "./logtest1" } }'
testing
hello world
```

The file "logtest1" is not even being created.

Comment: Do you wait a while?  It can take time before the engine is ready.  Also, try turning on verbose/debug mode.

Comment: I think you were right, I was just being too impatient as it was much slower getting started on my linux box than my windows box

Comment: @AlainCollins if you want to put that as an answer, I will accept it.  Probably I am not the only impatient person to get confused by this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logstash engine can take a while to startup.  Patience is a virtue!

Comment: Thanks, turns out that was my whole problem, but I was using Ctrl-C to terminate the process after trying a few inputs, and never waiting long enough for it to finish starting up!